# Qlik with header authentication retrieving apps

Tags: php, authentication, header, qliksense

Im using Qlik Sense with header authentication, but for some reason when I run requests to the qrs/apps/full?Xrftoken=lskadjfalkjd I only get the public apps. 
How do I set the user attributes to retrieve all the apps for the user?

Below is my implantation of the qlik request in php:

```
private static function getRequestHeaders($email)
{
    $user = AuthClass::getUser();

    $id   = $user['UserId'];
    $dir  = $user['UserDirectory'];
    $atts = $user['Attributes'];

    $securityHeaders = 'SecureRequest=true; Context=AppAccess;';

    foreach ($atts as $attr)
    {
        $key              = key($attr);
        $val              = $attr[$key];
        $securityHeaders .= "{$key}={$val}; ";
    }

    return [
        'headers' => 
        [
            'X-Qlik-xrfkey: ' . self::$xrfToken,
            'hdr-usr: Users\\' . $email,
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            "X-Qlik-Security: $securityHeaders",
            "X-Qlik-User: UserDirectory={$dir};UserId={$id}",
        ]
    ];
}

$res = CurlHelper::get(
   'server/qps/app/full?Xrftoken=039498543', 
   self::getRequestHeaders($email)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

A few notes from someone who has no background in PHP:

- You're calling `qps/app/full` rather than `qrs/app/full`
- It should be Xrfkey not Xrftoken, e.g. `qrs/app/full?Xrfkey=01234567890123456`
- The Xrfkey needs to be 16 characters alpha-numeric
- This assumes that https://server.company.com has a virtual proxy with header auth without a prefix
- It's preferable for back-end integrations to call QRS directly over port 4242 which requires a bit extra:

  - Passing the internal client certificate with key
  - Changing things from using the header in the Virtual Proxy to using `X-Qlik-User: UserDirectory=<directory>; UserId=<userid>`

References:

- [Xrfkeys](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2019/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-Connect-API-Using-Xrfkey-Headers.htm)
- [X-Qlik-User](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2019/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-Injected-Request-Headers-X-Qlik-User.htm)
- [Connecting using PHP](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2019/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-Example-Connect-PHP.htm)

Comment: HI there. the things you pointed out above were just typos. Regarding using the certificate way then yes I already know this. There is a particular reason we are using the header authentication way. That is why we are migrating over to the header authentication method. Hence the question